# Publishing Custom Elements, naming conventions, best practices?

Tags: web-component, custom-element

I am about to make my Custom Element `<card-t>` public

pre-release is at: https://github.com/card-ts/playingcardts

**Suggestions and enhancements much appreciated!**

Couple of questions:

#### Naming Custom Elements

There is: https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/how-should-i-name-my-element
but it doesn't get past "must include a hyphen"

I went with `element.card-t.js` for sorting purposes.

Other best practices ??

#### Wrapping in IIFE & ES Modules?

The Custom Elements gets created in the Global Namespace, and doesn't return anything like a library does.

Wrapping in an IIFE should be enough?

Is there value in loading it as module?

`<script type="module" src="element.card-t.js">`

#### Extending Custom Elements

Should we by default return the class definition so extending is easier?

Comment: I made a "web namespace registry" where we can search for existing namespaces https://github.com/nuxodin/web-namespace-registry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an opinion question these are my opinions:

### Naming Custom Elements

I always name my JS file based on my class name and my class name is just the tag name but capitalized. So my tag `<my-thing>` would have a class name of `MyThing` and my filename would be `components/MyThing.js`

### Wrapping in IIFE & ES Modules?

I create all of my code in ES6+ and then I create an additional ES5 CommonJS version and an ES5 IIFE version and let people load what they want.

I use `rollup` and my **[component-build-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/component-build-tools)** to create my various versions. **component-build-tools** component-build-tools also combines all dependencies of a component into the output file. This can lead to some replication, but most of the time that is small enough I don't mind.

My components end up with their templates and locale strings embedded into the published files. This is a feature of **component-build-tools**.

### Extending Custom Elements

As a general rule I expose the class name in all three formats of my files. This does help with extending my components, yet I doubt that many people will ever want to do that.

### Where to place the files.

The hardest thing is where to place the files so they are easily accessed by the web page.

I have a build step that copies my files from the `node_modules` folder into a dist folder. This was the easiest thing for me to know exactly where my files are located.

Doing this allows me to `npm install` anything and then still get their files into a location I know and can use. But it also has lead to me not worrying greatly about where my files end up in my repo.

I do tend to have a `dist` folder and in there I have:

```
dist
 +- js
     +- components
         +- MyThing.js
         +- MyThing.min.js
         +- AnotherThing.js
         +- AnotherThing.min.js
         +- SoOn.js
         +- SoOn.min.js
```

Comment: Yes, an opinion question... and opinions create standards...I will look into your tool. What are the **three** formats? Extending can only be done from a Class Definition?. I agree, yes, the class definition is ``MyThing`` <opinion> but I prefer ``element.my-thing.js`` for the file name as it does **not** require any mental translation _oh yes! CamelCase are dashes_ We programmers are used to it. _tag-slingers_ are not.

Comment: The three output formats are **module** using `import`, **commonjs** using `require` and **iife** using standard `<script>` tags.